# Как задать запрос на выборку записей из главной таблицы, сортируемых по данным из второстепенных таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть 3 таблицы (скриншоты показаны ниже):

- `Product (ProductID,Product_name,Category_ID,Type_ID)`,
- `Category (CategoryID,Category_name)`,
- `Type (Type_ID,Type_name)`.

Я хотел бы узнать, как сделать поиск наименований продукта (`Product_name`), например, по его категории (`Category_name`)?
Например, если задать выборку по `Category B`, то должно выдать только `ggggg`
Помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Comment: А что собственно значит _поиск наименьшего продукта по его категории_?  Отредактируйте вопрос, приведите примеры данных и _хотя бы_ желаемый результат.

Comment: Вопрос отредактировал, пример желаемого результата привёл

Comment: Так у вас и так будет выведено только `gggg` для фильтра по категории `Category B`.

Comment: Я имею ввиду как такой запрос оформить? Я понимаю что можно по category_id это оформить SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id=2 (или как-то так), но как это оформить используя таблицу Category и поле category_name?

Answer (score 0):

Например, вот так:

```
SELECT `product_name` FROM `product` WHERE `category_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `category` WHERE `name` = 'something nice');
```

Я уверен, что кто-нибудь посоветует решение с `JOIN`, которое, ввозможно, будет даже более производительным.

Comment: спасибо большое